# How can I save an image taken through AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, avcapturesession

I've set up a custom camera view that has overlay buttons on the view.  Everything works as it should.  The camera takes the picture, and the picture shows up in a UIImageView.  How do I save this picture once it's in the UIImageView?

Code below:

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *frameForCapture;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

AVCaptureSession *session;

AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];

    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput]){
        [session addInput:deviceInput];
    }

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view]layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame = self.frameForCapture.frame;

    [previewLayer setFrame:frame];

    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}


- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections){
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]){
            if([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]){
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (imageDataSampleBuffer != NULL) {
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
            self.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Comment: Where do you want to save this picture?

Comment: technically you can use the same UIImage instance that's loaded into the UIImageView

Comment: I want to save it to the camera roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to save image in device

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, id completionTarget, SEL completionSelector, void *contextInfo);
```

You only need completionTarget, completionSelector and contextInfo if you want to be notified when the image is done saving, otherwise you can pass in nil.